# How to delete the second element from the list?

Tags: xpath, selenium

I am having Three element with Delete option append with each element, How can i delete only the third element ?

**Example** :
Element1 with delete button
Element2 with delete button
Element3 with delete button.

When i run the script,it should go click on the delete button of third element & delete the record. Anyone kindly help me to proceed with this,, i am new to the selenium.

Below operation i have performed :
i have taken the xpath of delete button.

`driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@title='Remove']"));`

but how to click on the element.

Comment: can you provide ur html code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking to access the third element of the List ? If so, you can do that by

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@title='Remove']")).get(2).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

findElements() returns a list of matching elements. So if you want to act on the third element button, then you can do like this,

```
List<WebElement> deleteButtons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@title='Remove']"));
deleteButtons.get(2).click();
```

While this may work for you, it is not the best option to use. If the developer changes the positions of the elements then above code may click the wrong button. Instead create your xpath relative to the Element3. That way you are sure it will always click the correct button regardless of its position on the page.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using link instead of button. There will be a link against each of element, when u click on delete link, u can pass element_id in query string and then by retrieving that id u can delete corresponding record.
For example:
    ">Delete

Comment: I have tried with,All the name almost same, Need a unique property to identify that delete option.